# Loading WAV file with XAudio2

Tags: c++, audio, wav, xaudio2, riff

I'm writing a program which I can load and play a WAV file,  I'm using XAudio2 library, I started writing it with help from msdn.microsoft.com, and now I have almost exactly copied code from msdn and it still does not work. I don't know where is the problem. When I try to play sound with CreateSourceVoice I have XAUDIO2_E_INVALID_CALL error.
I'll be grateful for help.
His is my code:

My temporary main:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
TCHAR * strFileName = _TEXT("Chimes.wav");
//Creating a instance od XAufio2 Engine
IXAudio2* pXAudio2;
IXAudio2MasteringVoice* pMasteringVoice;
IXAudio2SourceVoice* pSourceVoice;
HRESULT hr;

if ( FAILED( hr = XAudio2Create( &pXAudio2, 0, XAUDIO2_DEFAULT_PROCESSOR ) ) ){
    cout << "XAudio2Create Failed!\n";
}

WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE wfx = { 0 };
XAUDIO2_BUFFER buffer = { 0 };

//Open the audio file with CreateFile

HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(
    strFileName,
    GENERIC_READ,
    FILE_SHARE_READ,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    0,
    NULL
    );

DWORD dwChunkPosition = 0;
DWORD dwChunkSize;


if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFile)
    cout << "INVALID HANDLE VALUE!\n";
    //return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
if (INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER == SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, NULL, FILE_BEGIN))
{
    cout << "INVALID SET FILE POINTER!\n";
    //return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
}

cout << "Locating a 'RIFF' and whole data size\n";
FindChunk(hFile, fourccRIFF, dwChunkSize, dwChunkPosition);

cout << "Checking a filetype\n";
DWORD filetype;
ReadChunkData(hFile, &filetype, sizeof(DWORD), dwChunkPosition);

if (filetype != fourccWAVE)
    cout << "This isn't WAVE file!\n";
else cout << "WAVE format!\n";

cout << "Locating a fmt and filling out WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE structure\n";
FindChunk(hFile, fourccFMT, dwChunkSize, dwChunkPosition);
ReadChunkData(hFile, &wfx, dwChunkSize, dwChunkPosition);

cout << "Locating a DATA\n";
FindChunk(hFile, fourccDATA, dwChunkSize, dwChunkPosition);

cout << "Reading a sound\n";
BYTE * pDataBuffer = new BYTE[dwChunkSize];
ReadChunkData(hFile, pDataBuffer, dwChunkSize, dwChunkPosition);
buffer.AudioBytes = dwChunkSize;
buffer.pAudioData = pDataBuffer;
buffer.Flags = XAUDIO2_END_OF_STREAM;

//Plaing preloaded sound;
if (FAILED(hr = pXAudio2->CreateSourceVoice(&pSourceVoice, (WAVEFORMATEX*)&wfx)))
    cout << "Playing sound Failed!\n";

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

And functions to searching Chunks in WAV file:

```
HRESULT FindChunk(HANDLE hFile, DWORD fourcc, DWORD & dwChunkSize, DWORD & dwChunkDataPosition)
{
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
if (INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER == SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, NULL, FILE_BEGIN))
    return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());

DWORD dwChunkType;
DWORD dwChunkDataSize;
DWORD dwRIFFDataSize = 0;
DWORD dwFileType;
DWORD bytesRead = 0;
DWORD dwOffset = 0;

while (hr == S_OK)
{
    DWORD dwRead;
    if (0 == ReadFile(hFile, &dwChunkType, sizeof(DWORD), &dwRead, NULL))
        hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());

    if (0 == ReadFile(hFile, &dwChunkDataSize, sizeof(DWORD), &dwRead, NULL))
        hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());

    switch (dwChunkType)
    {
    case fourccRIFF:
        dwRIFFDataSize = dwChunkDataSize;
        dwChunkDataSize = 4;
        if (0 == ReadFile(hFile, &dwFileType, sizeof(DWORD), &dwRead, NULL))
            hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
        break;

    default:
        if (INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER == SetFilePointer(hFile, dwChunkDataSize, NULL, FILE_CURRENT))
            return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
    }

    dwOffset += sizeof(DWORD)* 2;

    if (dwChunkType == fourcc)
    {
        dwChunkSize = dwChunkDataSize;
        dwChunkDataPosition = dwOffset;
        return S_OK;
    }

    dwOffset += dwChunkDataSize;

    if (bytesRead >= dwRIFFDataSize) return S_FALSE;

}

return S_OK;

}

HRESULT ReadChunkData(HANDLE hFile, void * buffer, DWORD buffersize, DWORD bufferoffset)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
if (INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER == SetFilePointer(hFile, bufferoffset, NULL, FILE_BEGIN))
    return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
DWORD dwRead;
if (0 == ReadFile(hFile, buffer, buffersize, &dwRead, NULL))
    hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
return hr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where do you instantiate your mastering voice (pMasteringVoice)? The XAudio2 graph expects Source Voice -> Mastering Voice -> XAudio2.

Add the following after your XAudio2Create call

```
IXAudio2MasteringVoice* pMasteringVoice = NULL;
if ( FAILED(hr = pXAudio2->CreateMasteringVoice( &pMasteringVoice ) ) )
    return hr;
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415779(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415779%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)